# Accessibility setting on modal webpage

Tags: accessibility

I have web page where backend polling call happens and update the content continuously for 2 minutes. As content on page updates screen reader finding the content as new and it is reading out but by the time it reads all previously updated content it is not getting enough to read the actual content and it is getting missed out. Is there any way can I use some aria attributes to Minimize it.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a [Live Region](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Live_Regions)

This is practically adding ARIA attributes to the element that will contain your updating content.

```
<div role="region" aria-live="polite">
```